# what is the time complexity of std::next_permutation() function in c++?

Tags: c++, stl

I wanted to know the time complexity of the next_permutation function. Can I view its code too ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/next_permutation.html:

> Linear. At most (last - first) / 2
>   swaps.

To see the source code, just look in STL header files for your system.  On a Unix-like system, you probably need to look somewhere like `/usr/include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algo.h`.

Comment: Actually, it's better than linear. It's amortised O(1) — i.e., if you call it n! times, it takes only O(n!) operations, not n*n!. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973077/the-amortized-complexity-of-stdnext-permutation).