# Combination of 1 and 0 in an array in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, combinations, python-itertools

I want to make a combination of 1's and 0's in a 2d array like the following:

```
[[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
 [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
 [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
 [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
 [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ],
 .
 .
 .
]
```

That means a combination of four 1's and four 0's. I have looked at the `itertools` module's `permutations()` and `combinations()`, but couldn't find any suitable functions to perform this combination.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534430/why-does-pythons-itertools-permutations-contain-duplicates-when-the-original

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use `combinations` to generate unique combinations directly:

```
n = 8
n1 = 4
for x in itertools.combinations( xrange(n), n1 ) :
    print [ 1 if i in x else 0 for i in xrange(n) ] 

[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
...
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

This is more efficient than `permutations` because you don't iterate over unwanted solutions.

The intuition is that you're trying to find all possible ways to fit four "1"s in a sequence of length 8; that's the exact definition of [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). That number is `C(8,4)=8! / (4! * 4!) = 70`. In contrast, the solution using `permutations` iterates over `8! = 40,320` candidate solutions.

Comment: +1 However, I'd still prefer the `permutations` solution, particularly the one-liner, as it is immediately clear what the code does, and the generation-overhead is not that big either (but might be for more bits).

Comment: That's the thing I wanted. Thanks a lot usual me.

Comment: @tobias_k: the solution using `permutations` might be more readable, but try to use it with `n>15`...

Comment: Ah, found the term: *multiset permutation*.

Comment: @usualme Yes, that's basically what I wanted to express in my comment. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are producing a [permutation of a multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets).

The simple but naive approach is to use [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), with a set to filter out repeated combinations:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> seen = set()
>>> for combo in permutations([1] * 4 + [0] * 4):
...     if combo not in seen:
...         seen.add(combo)
...         print combo
...
(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
# ...
(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

or, producing the whole sequence in one go:

```
set(permutations([1] * 4 + [0] * 4))
```

but this loses the order that `permutations` produced.

The set is needed as `permutations()` sees the 4 `1` and 4 `0` as individual characters and one `1` swapped with another is considered a unique permutation.

You could also use the ordering in the sequence to avoid having to use a set:

```
last = (1,) * 8
for combo in permutations([1] * 4 + [0] * 4):
    if combo < last:
        last = combo
        print combo
```

The approach is naive in that 2n! permutations are produced where we only want (2n choose n) elements. For your case that's 40320 permutations where we only need to produce 70.

Comment: Or just `set(itertools.permutations([1]*4+[0]*4))`?

Comment: @tobias_k: Yup, but then you are forced to produce the whole set in one go, and order might be important.

Comment: Since the set has only 70 elements, I don't think this is much of a problem, neither is sorting the set like `sorted(set(...), reverse=True)`. +1

Comment: Thanks tobias_k. It is done. But how can I formulate it like a matrix as I have given the question. Like [[],[],[]] format

Comment: @user3812253: `permutations()` produces tuples; you can easily call `list()` on each not-yet-seen result and add that to a list.

Comment: @user3812253: or use `sorted(map(list, set(permutations([1]*4+[0]*4))), reverse=True)` to produce a list of lists.