# how to create a list of lists using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I want to create a list of lists using list comprehension.
ex 
[range(3),range(3),range(3)]
i.e all possible coordinates of a 3d system from 0 to 3
How to do this using only list comprehension and nothing else

I tried doing

```
coordinates=[x for x in range(3)[y for y in range(3)[z for z in range(3)]]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your current code and where you're having the problem, and then state what the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combination of 1 and 0 in an array in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609919/combination-of-1-and-0-in-an-array-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

your syntax is slightly off

```
coordinates=[[x,y,z] for x in range(4) for y in range(4) for z in range(4)]
```

Comment: `coordinates = list(map(list, itertools.product(range(4), repeat=3)))`

Answer (score 2):

```
[[n,d,e] for e in [0,1,1] for d in [0,0,0] for n in [1,1,1]]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0],
<..>
```

Change/add variables and source lists as needed.