# Sorted number permutations list from numeric variables or numeric list with no duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x

Number permutations function, creates a list of all possible arrangements.
Worked on this code for a while, it works well and I'm trying to find a shorter an more efficient way of writing it.

```
a = [3,7,9]
perms = lambda a:list(sorted(z) for z in map(lambda p:dict.fromkeys([str(sum(v* (10**(len(p) -1 - i)) for i,v in enumerate(item))).zfill(len(a)) for item in itertools.permutations(p)]).keys(), [[int(x) for x in ''.join(str(i) for i in a)]]))[0]
```

The code returns:

```
['379', '397', '739', '793', '937', '973']
```

You can also input numeric string variable

```
a = '468'
perms(a)
['468', '486', '648', '684', '846', '864']
```

This is code is different, instead of returning tuples or list. It returns a list of results in string format. Also, you are allowed to input numeric strings, tuples or lists. Trust me I've checked any duplicates before posting.

The triple digits work pretty well

```
perms('000')
['000']
```

Other codes produces this

```
['000', '000', '000', '000', '000', '000']
```

Also, this code returns an ordered list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: If you are allowed to use modules, then : https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.permutations

Comment: I found this article extremely helpful for learning how to generate permutations. http://sahandsaba.com/combinatorial-generation-using-coroutines-in-python.html

Comment: @ Marcel Wilson The article is simple and easy to follow, I provided examples and results,  and what I am looking for. The list is sorted from smallest to largest, don't you notice that in the results. My objective is to find a more efficient way at writing this code. What isn't there to understand about this article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.permutations), why not just:

```
def perms(iterable):
    return [''.join(p) for p in (map(str, perm) for perm in itertools.permutations(iterable))]

>>> perms('123')
# Result: ['123', '132', '213', '231', '312', '321']
```

**Update:** If you wish to avoid duplicates, you can extend the functionality like so by using a set, as elaborated on in [Why does Python's itertools.permutations contain duplicates? (When the original list has duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534430/why-does-pythons-itertools-permutations-contain-duplicates-when-the-original)

```
def unique_perms(iterable):
    perm_set = set()
    permutations = [i for i in itertools.permutations(iterable) if i not in perm_set and not perm_set.add(i)]
    return [''.join(p) for p in (map(str, perm) for perm in permutations)]
```

This is still significantly faster than the posters original method, especially for examples like '000' and is stable (preserves permutation order).

Comment: ok, what's the issue? Seems to fit your spec and example use cases

Comment: Code works for me.  And it's more than 2x faster.  
<lambda> x 100000: 2.33799177202  
perms x 100000: 0.75015824786

Comment: @Marcel Wilson, awesome thanks for checking that.  I think OP was perhaps saying in comment that they didn't want duplicates, but I'll wait to hear confirmation on that before updating my answer.

Comment: Confirmed in question update, I'll update my answer.

Comment: iter is probably not the best variable name, probaby better to also yield each value

Comment: @lemonhead Just wrap the returned list in set()

Comment: @MarcelWilson, doing the `list(set(x))` trick certainly works, but I updated with another way which preserves the original order given by `itertools.permutations`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, for the general case I would certainly agree that it makes sense to return a generator instead of a list but I was just matching the interface for the OPs original function.

Comment: The second code should be put in a dark hole and never allowed surface again! Don;t use list comps for side effects and creating another list is now keeps almost two full copies of the data

Comment: That was just my choice for an efficient way of removing duplicates while preserving order without using something like an ordered set, e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order for whichever style you feel is most clear.