# Scheme - generate all distinct permutations of a list

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, scheme, racket, permutation

While reading a certain book about functional programming and scheme (and Racket) in particular, I happened upon an exercise which states the following: 
`

```
"Write a function 'rp' which takes, as an argument, a list 'lp' of pairs '(a . n)',
where 'a' is either a symbol or a number and 'n' is a natural number, 
and which returns the list of all the lists, whose elements are the 'a's defined by 
the pairs in 'lp', each one appearing exactly 'n' times."
```

For some reason this is really cryptic, but what it basically asks for is the list of all distinct permutations of a list containing **n** times the number/symbol **a**.

E.g : `[[(rp '((a . 2) (b . 1))]] = '((a a b) (a b a) (b a a))`

Generating the permutations, ignoring the `distinct` part, is fairly easy since there is a, relatively, straight forward recursive definition:

```
The list of permutations of an empty list, is a list containing an empty list.
The list of permutations of 3 elements a b c is a list containing the lists of all permutations of
a and b where, for each one, c has been inserted in all possible positions.
```

Which I translated in the following racket code:

```
(define permut
  (lambda(ls)
    (if(null? ls) '(())
       (apply append
              (map (lambda(l) (insert_perm (car ls) l))
                   (permut (cdr ls)))))))

(define insert_perm
  (lambda(x ls)
    (if(null? ls) (list (list x))
       (cons (cons x ls)
             (map (lambda(l) (cons (car ls) l))
                  (insert_perm x (cdr ls)))))))
```

This works, but does not return distinct permutations. Taking into account the duplicates seems to me much more complicated. Is there a simple modification of the simple permutation case that I cannot see? Is the solution completely different? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [permutation algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425070/algorithm-to-list-all-unique-permutations-of-numbers-contain-duplicates)

Comment: @tjorchrt you can check out the solution I finally came up with if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thought I came up with my own recursive definition that seems to work. This solution is an alternative to the one proposed in the answer by @Sorawee Porncharoenwase and can be defined as follows:

```
The distinct permutations of a list containing only one kind of element 
(e.g '(a a a)) is the list itself.
if (f l) gives the list of distinct permutations (lists) of l, 
where l contains x times each distinct element el_i, 0<=i<=n 
and if ll is the list l plus one element el_i, 0<=i<=n+1 (distinct or not)
Then the distinct permutations of ll is a list containing 
all the following possible concatenations:
el_i + (f l/{el_i}), where l/{el_i} is the list l excluding its ith distinct element.
```

To illustrate this definition, consider the following examples:

```
The list of all distinct permutations of (a b c) is the list containing
a + {(b c) (c b)} = (a b c) (a c b)
b + {(a c) (c a)} = (b a c) (b c a)
c + {(a b) (b a)} = (c a b) (c b a)

The list of all distinct permutations of (a a b) is the list containing: 
a + {(a b) (b a)} = (a a b) (a b a)
b + {(a a)} = (b a a)

etc...

Similarly, the list of all distinct permutations of (a a b c) is: 
a + {(a b c) ...} = (a a b c) (a a c b) (a b a c) (a b c a) (a c a b) (a c b a)
b + {(a a c) ...} = (a a c) (a c a) (c a a)
c + {(a a b) ...} = (a a b) (a b a) (b a a)
```

This leads to the following implementation:

```
(define unique_perm
  (lambda(ls)
    (if (= (length ls) 1)
        (list (build-list (cdar ls) (const (caar ls))))
        (apply append (map (lambda(p) (map (lambda(l) (cons (car p) l)) (unique_perm (update_ls ls p)))) ls)))))

(define update_ls
  (lambda(ls p)
    (cond ((null? ls) ls)
          ((equal? (caar ls) (car p))
           (if (= (- (cdar ls) 1) 0)
               (cdr ls)
               (cons (cons (caar ls) (- (cdar ls) 1)) (cdr ls))))
          (else (cons (car ls) (update_ls (cdr ls) p))))))
```

Example:

```
> (unique_perm_2 '((a . 3) (b . 2)))
'((a a a b b) (a a b a b) (a a b b a) (a b a a b) (a b a b a) (a b b a a) (b a a a b) (b a a b a) (b a b a a) (b b a a a))
```

Answer (score 1):

The change is pretty simple. When you have no duplicate, the following works:

> The list of permutations of 3 elements a b c is a list containing the lists of all permutations of a and b where, for each one, c has been inserted in all possible positions.

With duplicates, the above doesn't work anymore. A permutation of 2 elements a = "a", b = "b" is:

- "a" "b"
- "b" "a"

Now, consider c = "a". If you insert it in all possible positions, then you would get:

- c "a" "b" = "a" "a" "b"
- "a" c "b" = "a" "a" "b"
- "a" "b" c = "a" "b" "a"
- c "b" "a" = "a" "b" "a"
- "b" c "a" = "b" "a" "a"
- "b" "a" c = "b" "a" "a"

So instead, make a restriction that when you are inserting, you will only do it *before* the first occurrence of the same element that exists in the list that you are inserting to:

- c "a" "b" = "a" "a" "b" -- this is OK. c comes before the first occurrence of "a"
- "a" c "b" = "a" "a" "b" -- this is not OK. c comes after the first occurrence of "a"
- "a" "b" c = "a" "b" "a" -- this is not OK
- c "b" "a" = "a" "b" "a" -- this is OK
- "b" c "a" = "b" "a" "a" -- this is OK
- "b" "a" c = "b" "a" "a" -- this is not OK

This gives:

- "a" "a" "b"
- "a" "b" "a"
- "b" "a" "a"

as desired.

Moreover, you can see that this algorithm is a generalization of the algorithm that doesn't work with duplicates. When there's no duplicate, there's no "first occurrence", so you are allowed to insert everywhere.

---

By the way, here's how I would format your code in Racket/Scheme style:

```
(define (permut ls)
  (if (null? ls)
      '(())
      (apply append
             (map (lambda (l) (insert-perm (car ls) l))
                  (permut (cdr ls))))))

(define (insert-perm x ls)
  (if (null? ls)
      (list (list x))
      (cons (cons x ls)
            (map (lambda (l) (cons (car ls) l))
                 (insert-perm x (cdr ls))))))
```

Comment: Hi, after some thought I thought a different (equivalent) recursive definition than the generalization you gave. You can check it out in case you're interested. Also I would really appreciate it if you have any feedback as far as complexity is concerned. Could your solution be applied in a more efficient way?

Comment: inserting `a` into `(a b a)` should produce both `(a a b a)` and `(a b a a)` but per your description only the first one will be produced. so this is not at all self-evident that the overall algorithm is correct. it might well be, but it's not immediately apparent.

Comment: Agreed that it's not immediately apparent, For the case that you raised, `(a a b a)` arises from `a` + `(a b a)`. `(a b a a)` arises from `a` + `(b a a)`.