# Unique permutations with replicate items

Tags: python, python-2.7, statistics, permutation, python-itertools

I am trying to use Python-2.7 to play around with "Randomization Distributions", but can't find the right `itertool` to do the job.

Imagine I have the list `['A', 'B', 'B']`

Using `itertools.permuations()` will give me the following:

```
('A', 'B', 'B')
('A', 'B', 'B')
('B', 'A', 'B')
('B', 'B', 'A')
('B', 'A', 'B')
('B', 'B', 'A')
```

When what I really want is the permutations without the duplicates:

```
('A', 'B', 'B')
('B', 'A', 'B')
('B', 'B', 'A')
```

Of course I could filter, but on real-world size datasets, you get a combinatorial explosion with the first method, whereas as the second isn't so bad.

`fact(len(A) + len(B))` versus `fact(len(A) + len(B)) / (fact(len(A) * fact(len(B)))`

If `len(A) = 6` and `len(B) = 5`, that's `399,916,800` vs. `462`

Is there a tool for this?

*Sidenote:* if someone can come up with a more descriptive title so that this question is more searchable to others, I am open to suggestions. Please leave a comment.

Comment: I was worried I had missed a duplicate. As mentioned, its very difficult to find a descriptive title for this problem and similarly meaningful search terms. Here, however, is a very good solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836385/how-can-i-interleave-or-create-unique-permutations-of-two-stings-without-recurs/12837695#12837695