# Select array permutations where pattern elements match rule

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given an array `ary` of five elements:

```
ary = [true, true, true, false, false]
```

I want to take all permutations of `ary` where the two `false` values are non-consecutive, considering that the last position (index `4`) wraps around to the first (index `0`):

```
[true, false, true, false, true] #=> Selected
[true, true, false, true, false] #=> Selected
[false, true, true, true, false] #=> Rejected
```

I thought the answer might come down to `select` and `each_with_index` methods. I'm not sure how to relate the elements in the array using logical expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This recursive method generates the permutations directly, as opposed to generating large numbers of permutations and discarding those that do not satisfy the specification.

**Code**

```
def all_perms(arr_size, nbr_false)
  return nil if nbr_false > arr_size/2
  return [true]*arr_size if nbr_false.zero?
  recurse(arr_size, nbr_false, true)
end

def recurse(arr_size, nbr_false, full_arr)
  last_first = arr_size + 1 - 2*nbr_false
  (0..last_first).each_with_object([]) do |i,a|
    pre = [true]*i << false
    case nbr_false
    when 1
      a << pre + [true]*(arr_size-pre.size)
    else
      pre << true
      sub_arr_size = arr_size - pre.size - (i.zero? && full_arr ? 1 : 0)
      post = [true]*(arr_size-pre.size-sub_arr_size)
      recurse(sub_arr_size, nbr_false-1, false).each { |aa| a << pre + aa + post }
    end
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr_size  = 5
nbr_false = 2

b = all_perms(arr_size, nbr_false)
  #=> [[false, true, false, true, true],
  #    [false, true, true, false, true],
  #    [true, false, true, false, true],
  #    [true, false, true, true, false],
  #    [true, true, false, true, false]]
b == b.uniq
  #=> true
b.any? { |a| a.each_cons(2).any? { |x,y| x == false && y == false} }
  #=> false
b.any? { |a| a.first == false && a.last == false }
  #=> false
```

```
arr_size  = 8
nbr_false = 3

b = all_perms(arr_size, nbr_false)
  #=> [[false, true, false, true, false, true, true, true],
  #    [false, true, false, true, true, false, true, true],
  #    [false, true, false, true, true, true, false, true],
  #    [false, true, true, false, true, false, true, true],
  #    [false, true, true, false, true, true, false, true],
  #    [false, true, true, true, false, true, false, true],
  #    [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, true],
  #    [true, false, true, false, true, true, false, true],
  #    [true, false, true, false, true, true, true, false],
  #    [true, false, true, true, false, true, false, true],
  #    [true, false, true, true, false, true, true, false],
  #    [true, false, true, true, true, false, true, false],
  #    [true, true, false, true, false, true, false, true],
  #    [true, true, false, true, false, true, true, false],
  #    [true, true, false, true, true, false, true, false],
  #    [true, true, true, false, true, false, true, false]] 

b == b.uniq
  #=> true
b.any? { |a| a.each_cons(2).any? { |x,y| x == false && y == false} }
  #=> false
b.any? { |a| a.first == false && a.last == false }
  #=> false
```

**Notes**

- The valid permutations are the same for all arrays of a given size that contain the same number of `false` elements. I therefore made the arguments of `all_perms` the size of the desired array and the number of `false` elements it is to contain (the other elements all being `true`).
- The third argument of `recurse`, `full_arr`, is a boolean that equals `true` when `recurse`is called from `all_perms` but equals `false` when `recurse` is called from `recurse`. This was necessary to avoid permutations that start and end with `false` (the cycling condition that is to be avoided). When `full_arr` is `true` and `i #=> 0`, the last element of the sub-array being constructed must be `true`. In all other situations it may be `true` or `false`.
- The index `i` refers to the index of the sub-array being constructed at which the first `false` is located. If, for example, `arr_size #=> 4`, `nbr_false #=> 2` and `full_arr #=> false`, the index `i` of the first `false` can be `0` or `1`. It cannot be `2`, as that would require the last two elements to be `false`.

Comment: Nice. Do you know any generic method to calculate all the unique permutations of an array with non-unique elements?

Comment: @Eric, in general, no, but I'm sure there's an authoritative answer out there. In the case where, as here, `arr.uniq.size #=> 2`, we can reason as follows. Let `n` be the array size, `m` be the number of `false` elements and `n-m` be the number of `true` elements. There are `n` permutations of the elements of the array. Consider any one of those. Think of each of the `false`s as wearing a different coloured hat. How many ways can we rearrange the hats, keeping the same positions in the array. That would be `m!` (cont...)

Comment: ...For each of those, how many ways can the `n-m` `true`s be rearranged, keeping the same positions in the array? That's `(n-m)!`.  So the same permutation can be generated `m!(n-m)!` ways. Therefore, the number of unique permutations is `n!/(m!(n-m)!)`. Does that expression look familiar?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wasn't looking for the number of permutations but for the permutations themselves. I found this nice piece of [Python code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836385/how-can-i-interleave-or-create-unique-permutations-of-two-stings-without-recurs/12837695#12837695), adapted from Knuth's book. I wrote a Ruby Enumerator based on this code. 
 
It needs elements to be comparable, though, which isn't the case with standard Ruby booleans.

Comment: @CarySwoveland This is really amazing, thank you for giving me so much detail to learn from. Your approach of writing methods to allow changes to the arguments in the future is something I hope to emulate

Answer (score 1):

## Solution #1

The obvious example for one such array is :

```
[true,false,true,false,true]
```

If you switch one `false` with the middle `true`, the array isn't valid anymore.

If you switch one `false` with the left or right `true`, you get the same array, [rotated](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate) left or right.

So to get all the possible arrays, you just need :

```
base_array = [true,false,true,false,true]
Array.new(5){ |i| base_array.rotate(i) }
```

It outputs :

```
[[true, false, true, false, true],
 [false, true, false, true, true],
 [true, false, true, true, false],
 [false, true, true, false, true],
 [true, true, false, true, false]]
```

## Solution #2

The bruteforce solution would to create every unique permutation of `ary` and check that no consecutive elements are both false. To account for the wrap, the first element is appended to the array :

```
ary = [true, true, true, false, false]
ary.permutation.to_a.uniq.select do |a|
  (a + [a.first]).each_cons(2).all? { |x, y| x || y } 
end
```

If you want to get fancy, you could write :

```
ary = [true, true, true, false, false]
n = ary.size
ary.permutation.to_a.uniq.select do |a|
  a.cycle.take(n+1).each_cons(2).all?(&:any?)
end
```

Comment: This is brilliant, so useful to see different ways to solve a problem that was giving me a conceptual challenge. Thanks for offering two different approaches!

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty method might be to expand the arrays to account for the wrapping:

```
array = [ true, true, true, false, false ]

array.permutation.to_a.uniq.map do |set|
  [ set[-1] ] + set + [ set[0 ] ]
end.select do |set|
  set.chunk_while { |b,a| b == a }.all? do |chunk|
    chunk[0] == true or chunk.length == 1
  end
end.map do |set|
  set[1, set.length - 2]
end
```

This yields:

```
# => [
#   [true, true, false, true, false],
#   [true, false, true, true, false],
#   [true, false, true, false, true],
#   [false, true, true, false, true],
#   [false, true, false, true, true]]
```

Comment: Wow thank you- this is a really cool way for me to learn how to apply some methods I haven't used before

Answer (score 0):

Without any smart consideration, one way is:

```
ary.permutation
.to_a.uniq
.reject do
  |a|
  i, j = a.each_index.select{|i| a[i] == false}
  (i + 1) == j || j - 4 == i
end
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really neat. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "smart consideration", is it possible for you to say more about that?