# How to compute derangement (permutation) of a list with repeating elements

Tags: python, math, combinations, permutation

I have a list with repeating elements, i.e. `orig = [1,1,1,2,2,3]`.
I want to create a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) `b = f(orig)` such that for every location value in `b` is different from value in `orig`:

```
b[i] != orig[i], for all i
```

I know a solution when all element in `orig` are unique, but this is a harder case.

Developing a solution in python, but any language will do.

Comment: you can just iterate through the permutations until you find one that is actually a derangement. It will not be very efficient but will do

Comment: This seems out of scope, since you offer no solution attempt. But in principle it should work like: generate any random permutation. Identify two different indices, where the permuted value is against your expectations still identical to orignal. Swap these positions.

Comment: @guidot Would such a heuristic generate such permutations with uniform probability?

Comment: Yes, it would, if the initial permutation is random (but the original would also do) and you start at a random position and consider the list a cyclic for the reamaining swaps. There are also special cases, where a solution is impossible as in `[1, 1, 2]`, which should be considered.

Comment: @guidot I have implementation that works on similar principle but was hoping for something more elegant/efficient or simply standardised. Thanks though.

Comment: Adapted one of the solutions I offered to this task. Pretty efficient I think :)

Answer (score 2):

The not so-efficient solution is clearly

```
import itertools
set([s for s in itertools.permutations(orig) if not any([a == b for a, b in zip(s, orig)])])
```

A second method and first improvement is using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values) `perm_unique`:

```
 [s for s in perm_unique(orig) if not any([a == b for a, b in zip(s, orig)])]
```

A third method is to use this super quick `unique_permutations` [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836385/how-can-i-interleave-or-create-unique-permutations-of-two-strings-without-recur/12837695#12837695).

```
 import copy
 [copy.copy(s) for s in unique_permutations(orig) if not any([a == b for a, b in zip(s, orig)])]
```

In my notebook with `%%timeit` the initial method takes `841 µs`, and we improve to `266 µs` and then to `137 µs`.

**Edit**

Couldn't stop considering, made a small edit of the second method. Didn't have the time to dive into the last method. For explanation, first see the original post (link above). Then I only added the check `and el != elements[depth]` which forces the condition of the derangement. With this we arrive at a running time of `50 µs`.

```
from collections import Counter

def derangement_unique(elements):
    list_unique = Counter(elements)
    length_list = len(elements)  # will become depth in the next function
    placeholder = [0]*length_list  # will contain the result
    return derangement_unique_helper(elements, list_unique, placeholder, length_list-1)

def derangement_unique_helper(elements, list_unique, result_list, depth):
    if depth < 0:   # arrived at a solution
        yield tuple(result_list)
    else:
        # consider all elements and how many times they should still occur 
        for el, count in list_unique.items():
            # ... still required and not breaking the derangement requirement
            if count > 0 and el != elements[depth]:   
                result_list[depth] = el  # assignment element
                list_unique[el] -= 1   # substract number needed
                # loop for all possible continuations 
                for g in derangement_unique_helper(elements, list_unique, result_list, depth-1):
                    yield g
                list_unique[el] += 1


list(derangement_unique(orig))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list contains significant part of duplicates, it might be hard to find derangement quickly.

In this case you can try graph approach.

Treat initial list to make a graph where every item is connected with non-equal elements (easy for sorted list).

Then build perfect matching (if number of element is even) or near-perfect matching (for odd count, here you'll need find some suitable pair and join single node to it).

Edges of matching indicate swaps to make derangement.

Python library `networkx` should contain needed methods.